# Unable to load script, when referencing an extension method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, extension-methods

I have a really simple extension method that I am calling from a MonoBehavior.  When I use the method the Unity project fails to compile and states that the Behavior that is using the extension method can not be loaded, please fix compile errors and assign a valid script.

I've included the commented code in the behavior that works if I comment out the extension method call.

There are no errors in the Visual Studio project, and everything appears to be in order.

**The extension class:**

```
public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static void Clear(this Transform transform)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            Clear(child.transform);
            GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        GameObject.Destroy(transform.gameObject);
    }
}
```

**The behavior**

```
public partial class MeasureManager : Singleton<MeasureManager>
{
        void DeleteMeasurement(Measurement measurement)
        {
            //while (measurement.Container.transform.root.childCount > 0)
            //{
            //    DestroyImmediate(measurement.Container.transform.root.GetChild(0).gameObject);
            //}
            //DestroyImmediate(measurement.Container.transform.gameObject);

            measurement.Container.transform.Clear();

            Measurements.Remove(Measurements.Find(x => x.Name == measurement.Name));
            _current = null;
        }
}
```

Comment: The error message suggests that name of your script and name of your script class are not identical.

Comment: I have just tested your extension method and everything works! Could you please add a screenshot of the Unity Editor error?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I placed a namespace around the behavior, since that is what the HoloToolKit does and I placed this in the same namespace.  Removing the namespace seemed to have cleared things up.  That said, I can really determine what is happening in Unity to cause the confusion though